# Store boolean value and number to firestore in angular

Tags: angular, typescript, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire2

I am using Angular 5 typescript. I have a form in which there are multiple input fields and selection as well. I am catching the form values as:

```
let  locked: boolean = 
(<HTMLInputElement>document.getElementById("locked")).value;

let maxPlayers: number = 
(<HTMLInputElement>document.getElementById("maxPlayers")).value;
```

where locked is the boolean value which is catch from the selection and maxPlayers is the number value. And now i am storing these values to firestore as:

```
let id = this.afs.createId();
this.afs.collection("activities").doc(id).set({

 locked:locked,
 maxPlayers: maxPlayers,

 });
```

But both the values in the firestore are store as strings. I want to store them as number and boolean. How can i do this? any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
this.afs.collection("activities").doc(id).set({
  locked: (locked === 'true'),
  maxPlayers: Number(maxPlayers) 
});
```

This should do the trick. In the case of a number, you might have other ways of achieving the same thing depending on what type of numbers we are talking about.